# Component returned failure code: 0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE) [nsIFileURL.file]

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

I want to make a basic example Firefox add-on using [js-ctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes). First, I made a *.dll* file with a simple C code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}
```

The library file is fine. I tested it in another project.
I load it by js-ctypes code:

```
var {Cu , Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm", null);
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var prompts = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPromptService);
var dataUrl = self.data.url("Js-CtypeLib.dll");
dataUrl = Services.io.newURI(dataUrl,null,null).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL).file.path;
var lib, add;

try{
    console.log("Load library");
    lib = ctypes.open("Js-CtypeLib.dll");
    try{
        declareFunc();
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("Error declare function");
    }
}
catch(e){
    console.log("Error load Library!");
}

function declareFunc(){
    add = lib.declare("add", ctypes.default_abi, ctypes.int, ctypes.int, ctypes.int);
}

function test(){
    var rs = add(4,2);
    prompts.alert(null, "Result: ", rs);
    lib.close();
}

exports.test = test;
```

and then, I call *support.js* file by *index.js*

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var support = require("./support.js");
var button = buttons.ActionButton({
    id: "mozilla-link",
    label: "Visit Mozilla",
    icon: {
        "16": "./images/icon-16.png",
        "32": "./images/icon-32.png",
        "64": "./images/icon-64.png"
    },
    onClick: handleClick}
);

function handleClick(state) {
    support.test();
}
```

Finally, in cmd, I run it and get:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE) [nsIFileURL.file]
```

Full error text:
[image: this error]

Comment: Please describe what you are expecting to have happen/what you are attempting to accomplish. Please provide a complete [mcve] which which we can duplicate the problem.

Comment: You don't have to make a DLL, you can use the native platform libraries. To do that you can copy paste these examples - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Standard_OS_Libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark your addon as "unpacked" in the package.json. Then you must use a `file://` uri in the call to `ctypes.open(file_uri_here)`.

To get a file uri of a file in your addon you would do this:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var cr = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/chrome/chrome-registry;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIChromeRegistry);

var chromeURI_myLib = Services.io.newURI('chrome://youraddon/content/mySubFolder/myCFunctionsForUnix.so', 'UTF-8', null);
var localFile_myLib = cr.convertChromeURL(chromeURI_myLib);
var jarPath_myLib = localFile_myLib.spec; // "jar:file:///C:/Users/Vayeate/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/aecgxse.Unnamed%20Profile%201/extensions/youraddon@jetpack.xpi!/mySubFolder/myCFunctionsForUnix.so"
var filePath_myLib = localFilemyLib.path; 

ctypes.open(filePath_myLib);
```